# Auto populate select tags using jQuery and JSON

Tags: jquery, html, json, select, populate

I'm trying to get one select tag to populate based on the value of another select tag. The values for the populated select tag come from a JSON document.

The practical use here is for departing ferry terminals and what terminals they can reach.

Here is the code snippet I'm using

```
$(function(){
  $("select#departingfrom").change(function(){
    $.getJSON("/database.json", $(this).val(), function(ferries){
      var options = '';
      for (var key in ferries) {
        options += '<option value=' + key + '>' + key + '</option>';
      }
      $("select#arrivingto").html(options);
    });
  });
});
```

Here's a small example of the JSON document

```
var ferries = {
  "horseshoebay": {
    "departurebay": {},
    "langdale": {}
  },
  "departurebay": {
    "horeshoebay": {}
  },
  "tsawwassen": {
    "swartzbay": {},
    "dukepoint": {}
  },
  "swartzbay": {
    "tsawwassen": {},
    "fulfordharbour": {}
  },
  "dukepoint": {
    "tsawwassen": {}
  },
  "langdale": {
    "horeshoebay": {}
  },
  "fulfordharbour": {
    "swartzbay": {}
  }
},
```

And then the HTML

```
<select id="departingfrom">
  <option selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="tsawwassen">Tsawwassen (Vancouver)</option>
  <option value="swartzbay">Swartz Bay (Victoria)</option>
  <option value="dukepoint">Duke Point (Nanaimo)</option>
  <option value="departurebay">Departure Bay (Nanaimo)</option>
  <option value="horseshoebay">Horseshoe Bay (North Vancouver)</option>
  <option value="langdale">Langdale (Sunshine Coast)</option>
  <option value="fulfordharbour">Fulford Harbour (Salt Spring Island)</option>
</select>

<select id="arrivingto">
  <option selected="selected"></option>
</select>
```

I can't seem for the life of me to get the "function(ferries)" to run, so it makes me think that the .val is not working correctly. Let me know if you guys have any suggestions!

Comment: What exactly is in your JSON? and what are you trying to get out of it?

Comment: `options = '<option value=' + key + '>' + key + '</option>';` That line should have a `+` before the assigning `=`

Comment: It goes in a format like this

Departing (in example horseshoe bay)
   Arriving (in this case either departurebay or langdale)
     Times (not shown but they are there in the actual JSON doc)

Comment: You don't need to pass the val() to the json file..  I don't think it will know what to do with it will it?

Comment: @galaxyAbstractor added that in, still doesn't seem to work. Will edit original post.

Comment: @wirey I do have multiple departing terminals, in the example I only have one. so, I need to take the value of the original select tag then based on that value populate the other select tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your `JSON` document needs to be refactored a bit for easier iteration.

**Let's take this class for example.**

```
public class City
{
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int StateID { get; set; }
}
```

And let's say (using ASP.NET MVC & C#) we are **returning JSON** by doing this:

```
    // the theStateID will be for California in this example
    public JsonResult FilterCitiesByStateID(int theStateID)
    {
        List<City> citiesList = null;

        citiesList = new CustomDb().Cities.Where(x => x.StateID == 
                                                    stateID).ToList();

        return Json(citiesList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This will give us back a list of City objects for California. (*Pretend the CityID's are meaningful.)*

[image]

So now you just need to append them to your select list with the proper value and text.

```
var $request = $.get('/Controller/Action/', { theStateID: 1 });

$request.success(function (listOfOptions) {
    // Iterate over the cities returned and append them to the
    // select list you need
    $.each(listOfOptions, function (key, obj) {
        $('select#YourSelect')
            .append($("<option></option>")
                         .attr("value", obj.CityID) // The value will be the CityID
                         .text(obj.Name) // The text will be the City's Name
                     );
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem is that your JSON object isn't actually properly formed if your ajax request is actually returning:

```
var ferries = { ... }
```

Your JSON object should simply be

```
{ ... }
```

with no variable assignment in the response from the server.